# Java Sockets not working on Android (ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: java, android, sockets

When trying to connect to a socket with an Android client, I receive ECONNREFUSED ConnectException.

When I run the code on my PC, it works fine I am able to connect to the remote server (raspberry pi, haskell) without an issue (so we can exclude that possibility).

Relevant code from ConnectionManager.class (Error thrown in line s=connect):

```
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    try {
        s=connect();
        socket_out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
        socket_in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The connect function (error thrown in line "return new socket")

```
    private Socket connect() {
    try {
        return new Socket("Thereisarealip in here",Realport);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ConnectionManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

XML Permissions include the following

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<service android:name=".ConnectionManager"></service>
```

The ConnectionManager Java class is called from the mainthread using:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConnectionManager.class);
    startService(intent);
```

Comment: Is your phone/app on the lan (via wireless) which your pi and pc are  on - or is PI outside your lan?

Comment: Are you using emulator or real device ?

Comment: @Andy the PI is on a completely different network. It has a static IP and has working port forwarding. I can connect to it with my PC running the same code and it is also possible to connect to it using SSH on a phone.

Comment: @KhalidTaha I am running it via android studio, but on my real phone via USB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. The router did not allow any mobile devices in the wifi network to access static IP addresses, but instead redirected them to a custom page without throwing an error.

Comment: Only to add that final solution is then to add the static IP addresses used in the network to the lease list of the local DHCP server. In a Router this is done usually in the "DHCP Static IP Lease" menu where it is requested to add the machine MAC address and its static IP address.

Answer (score 1):

ECONNREFUSED is only thrown when the server is either not listening on the specified port or it is not able to handle the request. Make sure that your server is able to receive connections continuously. For that listen for incoming connections on one thread and handle them on other thread without blocking the listening process. As I can see the INTERNET permission is already declared in the manifest so the problem can only be on server side.

Comment: This is curious though, cause the identical code, same IP, same port, same exact thing runs perfectly everytime when I run it on my PC, so how can that possibly be a server error?

Comment: Is there a viable network route from the Android device to the network (are you using Wifi or Cellular?) that contains the router that is sitting between your Android device and the Pi? Can your Android device [ping the IP](https://superuser.com/questions/586469/how-to-ping-an-ip-address-from-an-android-device) that it is trying to connect to? Just because the PC has a route to the IP doesn't guarantee the Android device has a route to the same IP.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Wifi only. The router used is the same one that my PC uses. Will try to ping it from my android device as well